# Expression Tree C# - Null-Conditional oeprator (?.)

Tags: c#, expression-trees, system.reflection

I'm trying to build in Expression Trees equivalent of "?." operator.

```
var member = Expression.Property(Expression.Property("PropertyObjectName", value.Property), 
    "PropertyOfObject");
```

which is:   `member.PropertyObjectName.PropertyOfObject`  which of course will **throw** `Null exception` if `PropertyObjectName` is `null` which I want to avoid.

Is there any way to build `member?.PropertyObjectName?.PropertyOfObject` other then putting there `ConditionalExpression`?

Comment: The `?.` is syntactic sugar, you should build the expression step by step with `Expression.IfThenElse()`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Expression.Condition will not be better then?

Comment: Yes, That would be better, i guess

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39617419/4685428) answer

Comment: Since `?.` still has no natural support in expression trees, and if you want to keep it compatible with query providers (i.e. don't use block expressions), there is no other way that simulating it via (nested) `Expression.Condition`. But note that the query providers which translate such expressions naturally support null propagation on `.` ( there are no "objects" in sql, hence no NRE), so in such case you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use my Extension method

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
    {
        public static Expression ElvisOperator(this Expression expression, string propertyOrField)
        {
            return Expression.Condition(Expression.NotEqual(expression, Expression.Constant(null)),
                Expression.PropertyOrField(expression, propertyOrField),
                Expression.Constant(null, expression.Type)
                );
        }
    }
```

this generates something like

```
IIF((x != null), x.propertyname, null)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
public class TestClass
    {
        public int FirstProp { get; set; }

        public TestClass SecondProp { get; set; } 
    }


var variable = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TestClass), "x");
var nullSafe = variable.ElvisOperator("SecondProp");
```

I made this test:

```
List<TestClass> tests = new List<TestClass>(){
            new TestClass() { FirstProp = 1, SecondProp = new TestClass() { SecondProp = new TestClass() } },
            new TestClass() { FirstProp = 2 },
            new TestClass() { FirstProp = 3, SecondProp = new TestClass() },
            new TestClass() { FirstProp = 4 },
        };

        var variable = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TestClass), "x");
        var nullSafe = variable.ElvisOperator("SecondProp").ElvisOperator("SecondProp");
        var cond = Expression.NotEqual(nullSafe, Expression.Constant(null, variable.Type));

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TestClass, bool>>(cond, new ParameterExpression[] { variable });

        tests = tests.AsQueryable().Where(lambda).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(tests.Count);
```

This prints 1 on the console because filters the list like this:

```
.Where(x => x.SecondProp?SecondProp != null)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this implementation is _not_ actually equivalent to the null-conditional operator. The actual C# operator will retrieve the possibly-null expression _once_, and then use that throughout. This makes it, for example, perfectly suited for raising C# events in a thread-safe way. IMHO it is erroneous and dangerous to provide a proposed implementation for the operator that doesn't have the same behavior as the actual operator.