# Expression lambda conversion to expression trees - error CS8072

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

The following expression lambda is fine (compiles and runs):

```
 Func<string, int> test = s => s?.Length ?? 0;
 Console.WriteLine(test("t")); //1
```

Converting it to expression tree:

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<string, int>> e = s => s?.Length ?? 0;
Console.WriteLine(e);
```

Generates a compile-time error:

> error CS8072: An expression tree lambda may not contain a null
> propagating operator.

**Question:**

Why it is not allowed to convert the code from lambda to an expression tree?

Comment: Because it contains a null propagating operator, as the error message says. Some of the more recent features of C# are not yet supported in expression trees.

Comment: `Expressions` are stuck in the past, basically: Microsoft doesn't want to update them to support new language features. (If it did, then the authors of things like EF would also have to update those to account for the new language features)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. So it's a "not yet implemented" thing. I thought that -  logically it was  impossible.

Comment: Well, I don't know how feasible it would be to implement without explicit support in the System.Linq.Expressions namespace. As canton7 says, it's far from simple for various reasons.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/4727) and the linked issues.

Comment: @canton7 Thanks. There is also [that link](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/11321#issuecomment-473653649)  - which 
 is where this question was actually  taken from

Comment: More information here on SO: [Why can't I use the null propagation operator in lambda expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880025/why-cant-i-use-the-null-propagation-operator-in-lambda-expressions)