# Nullable Reference Types HiddenFor

Tags: c#, razor, nullable-reference-types

Simple example of a .cshtml, nullable reference types enabled.

```
@model Project.MyModel
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NullableSubModel.MyValue)
```

m.NullableSubModel warns dereference of a possibly null reference

I tried wrapping in an if, doesn't get rid of the warning.

```
@if (Model.NullableSubModel != null)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NullableSubModel.MyValue)
}
```

Tried null forgiving, though I hardly expected that to work...

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NullableSubModel?.MyValue)
```

I know I could use ! just to ignore the warning, but usually there's a better way.

EDIT:
This also doesn't work

```
Model.NullableSubModel ??= new NullableSubModel();
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NullableSubModel.MyValue)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, it is not your fault. It is limitation of the razor parser.
The C# code for this .cshtml file is not even yet generated.
The right solution here is to actually use the null-forgiving operator.
I understand that it may look wrong, but this is the right way.

From MS documentation about the [null-forgivin operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving):

> You can also use the null-forgiving operator when **you definitely know** that an expression can't be null but the compiler doesn't manage to recognize that.

If you still want to avoid it, there also a way to do it by extracting that object from the model into a separate variable.

```
@if (Model.NullableSubModel != null)
{
  var separateVariable = Model.NullableSubModel ?? new();
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => separateVariable.MyValue)
}
```

This will give the analyzer enough context to know that your separateVariable is not null. The new() constructor at the end will never be called. Please note, however, that this method will change the name of the input in your HTML form from NullableSubModel_MyValue to something like separateVariable_MyValue.

For reasons beyond the scope of this question, you won't be able to use the ? operator in this lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Intellisense doesn't know that `Model` and `m` in the Expression parameter to `HiddenFor` reference the same instance. Take this code (in- or outside of a razor view)

```cs
var m1 = new MyModel();
var m2 = m1;
if (m1.NullableSubModel != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m2.NullableSubModel.MyValue);  // assuming type string 
}
```

This will give you the same warning, you get in your code.

Side note: you mixed "null forgiving" and "null-conditional" operators. Your posted code uses the "null-conditional" operator which is not allowed in a lambda expression (s. [Why can't I use the null propagation operator in lambda expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880025/why-cant-i-use-the-null-propagation-operator-in-lambda-expressions)).

The `!` ("null forgiving" operator) is indeed just a local supression of the "possible null reference"-hint. But it's meant for scenarios like yours, e. g. when intellisense is overburdened.

If using such a suppression is not an option for you, you might try this (use at your own risk; I don't know if it works or has side effects):

```cs
@if (Model.NullableSubModel != null)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(_ => Model.NullableSubModel.MyValue)
}
```